# Recuperar el valor de salida de un Procedimiento Almacenado MySql + PHP

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando Recuperar la respuesta de un Procedimiento Realizado en MySql sin exito, espero me puedan ayudar.

/* PROCEDIMENTO ALMACENADO */ En MySql cuando realizo la consulta si me devuelve el valor

```
CREATE PROCEDURE newFormaPago2(IN _forma_pago VARCHAR(255), OUT _rpt VARCHAR(255)) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE respuesta int; 
   SELECT COUNT(forma_pago) INTO respuesta FROM forma_pago WHERE forma_pago = _forma_pago; 
   IF respuesta > 0 THEN INSERT INTO forma_pago(forma_pago) VALUES (_forma_pago); 
       SET _rpt = 'Registro Almacenado'; 
   ELSE 
       SET _rpt = 'Existe una Forma de Pago con ese nombre'; 
   END IF; 
END;
```

Si hago la consulta en MySql me devuelve lo que necesito.

```
CALL newFormaPago2('Yape', @rpt);
SELECT @rpt AS rpt;
```

Como envio los datos

```
$FormaPago = (isset($_POST['FormaPago'])) ? $_POST['FormaPago'] : null;
$query = 'call newFormaPago2("'.$FormaPago.'", @rpt);';
$objRespuesta = Consultas::FuncionMysql($query);

$registros = count($objRespuesta);
if($registros > 0)
{
    foreach ($objRespuesta as $item)
    {
        $rpt = $item['rpt'];    
    }
}
        
$json[] = array('rpt' => $rpt);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Tengo una función de la clase Consultas que recibe los datos y los procesa

```
 public static function FuncionMysql($sql, $respuesta) {
        $conexion = new Conexion();
        $consulta = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $consulta->execute();
        
        $consulta->closeCursor(); 
        
        $r = $conexion->query('SELECT @rpt AS rpt;');
        $resultado = $r->fetchColumn();
       
        return $resultado;
    }
```

espero su ayuda.

Comment: Una conexión para cada llamada..., esa implementación no te ayuda; si declaras una variable en una 1er llamada, la pierdes -con todo el contexto- en una 2da llamada.

Comment: claro por eso se usa $consulta->closeCursor(); para ejecutar una segunda query